# How to get full length body text from received SMS in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, sms

I have a receiver for incoming SMS declared in the manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".WakeupReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"
        android:stopWithTask="false">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999999857">
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

and I have an onReceive function inside the .WakeupReceiver :  BroadcastReceiver() class, with a function to get data from received SMS:

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    val (smsContact, smsBody) = getSMSContent(intent)

    //Do stuff with sms content here
}

fun getSMSContent(intent: Intent): Pair<String, String> {
        val data = intent.extras
        val pdusObj = data!!.get("pdus") as Array<*>
        for (i in pdusObj.indices) {
            val currentMessage = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)[0]
            else SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdusObj[0] as ByteArray)

            // TODO: Here we get the all information about SMS.
            //Apply your conditions and logic here to filter your SMS from various SMS
            // and extract your content from message body

            val phoneNumber = currentMessage.displayOriginatingAddress
            Log.e("receiver", phoneNumber)

            val senderNum = phoneNumber
            Log.e("receiver", senderNum)

            val smsContent = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody()
            Log.d("receiver","Message: "+smsContent) // Always max 67 characters!

            return Pair(senderNum, smsContent)
        }
        return Pair("","")
    }
```

It works very well, except I can't get the "smsContent" variable to grab the entire sms message. I only get 67 characters from it, the rest of it is cut away.

Any idea why and how to get the whole message into that string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use this snippet.
It is a BroadcastReceiver for incoming Text Messages.

```
class MessagingService : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val body: StringBuilder = StringBuilder()
        var number = ""
        val bundle: Bundle? = intent.extras
        val messages: Array<SmsMessage?>
        if (bundle != null) {
            val msgObjects: Array<*>? = bundle.get(Constant.SMS_BUNDLE) as Array<*>?
            messages = arrayOfNulls(msgObjects!!.size)
            for (i in messages.indices) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(msgObjects[i] as ByteArray?)
                body.append(messages[i]!!.messageBody)
                number = messages[i]!!.originatingAddress.toString()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value in Constants.SMS_BUNDLE?

Comment: const val SMS_BUNDLE: String = "pdus"